# BS_OWNERDRAW and GDI+

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I'm trying to create a launcher window with 5 "invisible" buttons that have a smaller partially transparent image centered inside them. The image inside changes depending on whether the user is hovering over the button. In this example the images are resources IDB_Website1 and IDB_Website2.

The images are in .png format. I'm using GDI+ and loading PNG files from resources with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI.

I've used BS_OWNERDRAW to handle the graphics of the button. The problem is that **I don't know how to link the "PNG from resources" code to the parent's WM_DRAWITEM**. With the current way I've done the code, I lose the transparency of the .png by going through HBITMAP.

Global variable:

```
HBITMAP globalpic;
```

Main wndproc:

```
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), NULL,
                          WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW,
                          190, 230, 260, 50, // <- the larger rect size
                          hWnd, (HMENU) HT_BUTTON1, hInst, NULL);
        HTButton = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLong(hwndButton, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) ButtonProc);
    }

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        DRAWITEMSTRUCT* lpDrawItem = (DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)lParam;
        HBITMAP hBmp;
        HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

        if (hovering) // <- mousehover detection, not included
        {
            gdi.CreateBM(IDB_Website2, _T("PNG"), hInst, hdc, 62, 100, 200, 40);
        } else {
            gdi.CreateBM(IDB_Website1, _T("PNG"), hInst, hdc, 62, 100, 200, 40);
        }

        hBmp = globalpic; // get the global var gdi.CreateBM created
        DeleteDC(hdc);

        BITMAP bm;
        GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
        HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC, hBmp);
        StretchBlt (lpDrawItem->hDC,
                    lpDrawItem->rcItem.left + 30,
                    lpDrawItem->rcItem.top + 5,
                    200, <- the width of image
                    40, <- the height of image
                    hMemDC,
                    0, 0,
                    bm.bmWidth,
                    bm.bmHeight,
                    SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldBmp);
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        DeleteObject(hBmp);
        break;
    }
```

class GDI's method CreateBM.

Currently, since I don't know of a better way, it sends the HBITMAP to the global variable globalpic. The problem is that by doing this, I lose transparency.

```
void CreateBM(UINT menuid, LPCTSTR pType, HMODULE hInst, HDC hdc, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    CGdiPlusBitmapResource m_pBitmap;
    m_pBitmap.Load(menuid, pType, hInst);
    m_pBitmap.m_pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(RGB(255, 255, 0), &globalpic);
    //m_pBitmap.m_pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(GetBkColor(hdc), &globalpic); // <- no-go either
}
```

Any way I could do this more directly? I feel that going through the HBITMAP route is completely unnecessary but I couldn't for the life of me figure out how I should do it.

Then again, if using the HBITMAP way is fine, any pointers on how I could make the color (I guess (RGB(255, 255, 0) ...?) transparent with the current implementation?

---

Answering to Hans:

I also have a GDI method like this, but it's unused at the moment because I couldn't get the image removed after drawing it (as is needed when hovering changes the image):

```
void Create(UINT menuid, LPCTSTR pType, HMODULE hInst, HDC hdc, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    Graphics grpx(hdc);

    ht_img = new CGdiPlusBitmapResource();
    ht_img -> Load(menuid, pType, hInst);
    grpx.DrawImage(*ht_img, x, y, w, h);
    delete ht_img;
}
```

Comment: GDI doesn't support transparency directly.  As long as you use GDI+, go whole-hog and also use it to draw the bitmap with Graphics::DrawImage()

Comment: Heya! I'm aware of that and I've tested a command like grpx.DrawImage(*ht_img, x, y, w, h); but I couldn't remove the image afterwards. How could I utilize it with the WM_DRAWITEM correctly? Please see my edit in the question.